# DocuSign: template sign position issue when establishing routing order

Tags: docusignapi

My question is related to a specific REST operation for sending an Envelope using a Template where there are at least 2 roles defined as Signers (Signer1, Signer2)
The template is defined as follows: there is a document uploaded, 2 roles as signers (with no routing order, no email, no name) and the position of the Sign for each signer.
I have tried from the API explorer, and this is the JSON request:

```
{
"emailSubject": "template to sign",
"status": "sent",
"templateId": "xxxxx",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "email": "email1@gmail.com",
        "name": "signer1",
        "roleName": "Signer1",
        "routingOrder": "1"
    },
    {
        "email": "email2@gmail.com",
        "name": "signer2",
        "roleName": "Signer2",
        "routingOrder": "2"
    }
]}
```

All works fine except for the possition of the sign for Signer2. It should only appear the square of the sign in the document. However, It behaves like this role does not exist, and all objects for signing are available to this user.
If this same Envelope is sent without the routing order for neither of both signers, the position of the sign works as defined in the template for both signers, i.e. it works as expected.

I don't know if it is a bug, or something I am doing wrong or didn't understand well, but the tests have been executed using the Docusign API explorer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**
You can update the routing order but you must:

1. Use the composite templates API feature to do so.
2. Tell DocuSign that you're changing the routing order from the template's original routing by setting a query parameter.

Full details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55034325/64904).

**Original answer**

First, try using the template for an envelope from the DocuSign webtool.

My guess from your question is that the template is not set up the way you want it.

When you use the tagger window of the web tool for your template, check that you're creating the signing tabs for the two different roles. There's a dropdown chooser for each role in the tagger window. See the screenshot. It sets the owner for the document tabs (fields) shown on the screen

Once the envelope (driven by the template) is working well from the DocuSign web tool, switch to using the API.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Larry for your answer.
What you say about the tagger window was already done.
As I said, from the same API explorer, **if routingOrder is not set** in the JSON request, it works perfectly, i.e. the position of the sign for both roles is placed according to the template. On the other hand, **if routingOrder is set** for both roles in the JSON request, the position of the sign for the 1st signer (role) is ok, but not for the 2nd signer. Why does the 2nd signer "lose" the sign position when the routingOrder is set?

Comment: My guess on this is that you shouldn't try to set the routing order via the roles object--set the routing order in the template. Is there a reason you need to change the routing order from what it is in the template? Also, you may be able to use the composite templates feature for your goal. It enables you to mix and match template info with dynamic info from your create envelope call.

Comment: The reason is to let the users decide whether to stablish a routing order.

Comment: @JesúsdeAriasFar Good news, you can do it, but a query parameter is needed too. See updated answer (at beginning)

Comment: Composite templates must be used. Good news is we have a code example. See updated answer

Comment: It finally worked with that query parameter, without the need of using composite templates. Thank you @LarryK for your help